# What is the fastest way to sync a database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, synchronization

I have a question, clearly since I'm here...

I have a source database (SQL Server 2008) and a destination database (also SQL Server 2008).  There are modifications which need to be done which means that a lot of the data has to pass through C# (converting coordinates, triangulation etc).  But how would you do it?

I'm looking for a few things here.  Right now I'm using a `SqlDataReader` and pulling the data into a `DataTable` and using the data like that in order to manipulate it before I push it into the destination database, but what would be a better (faster & more memory efficient) way of doing it?

Also, for data which does not need to be manipulated I'm still pulling it through in the same way, I assume there is a way of avoiding that which would be quicker?

Technical info:

- DB: 2 x SQL Server 2008 (source/dest) - On the same server
- Language: C# / .NET 3.5
- OS: Windows

Comment: A data-table seems to be a bit heavyweight if you're just reading and writing records one at a time, unless you're using it as a buffer.

Comment: Is the data conversion deterministic per record or will changes in one record affect others?

Comment: Can you do the processing in the database itself with SQLCLR? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131045.aspx

Comment: Robert - Not using it as a buffer at the moment as there is no need, but as I've been told that it might need to process upwards of 100 mill rows, I put it in place so that I CAN use it as a buffer..

Comment: Mathew - I'm not 100% sure what you mean here.  Basically I'm taking a record from one table, matching it with a record in another table and putting them together into a new table which has extra information.  It's a hacky way of doing a join, as a join wouldn't work in this scenario (unless you tell me it will!).  Once a record has been paired, it cannot be paired with a different record again, in that way they affect each other I guess...

Comment: Luke:  I could use SQLCLR, I am using it for some other things I am doing.  But the time consuming part of this is doing the pairing, once C# has it it does take some time to whip through all the records and modify them, but my main question is whether I can improve on this specific part.  I try to avoid SQLCLR unless there is a MASSIVE improvement to be had as debugging is a nightmare!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would insert the source data into a temp table(s) on to the destination database.

Then I would use SQL Merge to update the destination.

[MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

I would completely minimize the role that c# plays.

Comment: This makes sense.  I mean C# does kinda have to do some of the work for some tables.  But I could use this for the tables which do not need to be modified! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the .NET code onto the sql server using the [SQL CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) in order to remove the round-trip time between the database and the machine.

Comment: I could use SQLCLR, I am using it for some other things I am doing. But the time consuming part of this is doing the pairing, once C# has it it does take some time to whip through all the records and modify them, but my main question is whether I can improve on this specific part. I try to avoid SQLCLR unless there is a MASSIVE improvement to be had as debugging is a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/enterprise-information-management/integration.aspx) for ETL tasks.

Comment: I'll look into this a little more, but I'm not sure I'd have the time to implement this.  It needs to be triggered by a user action, which I know Integration Services CAN do, but I'm not too familiar with them, and in the time I have I'm not sure I can implement a good enough solution to warrant the lost time.  Unless you think that it's really easy and are willing to give me a had ;-)